# mongodb query not using index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I have a index:

```
{
    "sourceName" : 1,
    "addedDate" : 1,
    "sourceKey" : 1,
    "appKey" : 1,
}
```

But when I try to do

```
db.myCollection.find({and:[
               {sourceName: "mySourceName"},
               {addedDate: 1414878162405},
               {sourceKey:"mySource Key"},
               {appKey: "test"}]
               }).explain()
```

It shows cursor is BasicCursor i.e it is not using the index:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 500,
    "nscanned" : 500,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 500,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 500,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    ...
}
```

Can anyone please explain me why my query is not using defined index??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query object uses `and` instead of the `$and` operator so it's looking for an field named 'and' in your documents that contains your query values.

But you don't need to be using `$and` anyway, as multiple query terms are implicitly ANDed so you can just do:

```
db.myCollection.find({
       sourceName: "mySourceName",
       addedDate: 1414878162405,
       sourceKey:"mySource Key",
       appKey: "test"}
   }).explain()
```

That should be able to use your index just fine.

Comment: I cannot believe I was missing that. Thanks a lot!